# Validation not firing properly

Tags: formula, validation

I have a validation rule: When the stage name is changed to "4. Proposal" then the max discount should be > 5 and Special_Pricing_Approved should be = false.

My validation rule:

```
IF((ISPICKVAL(StageName , "4. Proposal")),
And(Max_Discount__c < 5, Special_Pricing_Approved__c == true),null)
```

Is this the correct rule as per my requirement? This validation gets fired when max discount > 5 or < 5 same with pecial_Pricing_Approved get fire if it is true or false. What is wrong with my validation rule?

Error from debug:

```
VALIDATION_RULE|Opportunity_to_Proposal
|VALIDATION_FORMULA|AND(
ISPICKVAL(StageName , "4. Proposal")
,
OR(Max_Discount__c <= 5
   ,
   Special_Pricing_Approved__c = true
)
)|Max_Discount__c=21.05 , StageName=4. Proposal , Special_Pricing_Approved__c=0
VALIDATION_FAIL
```

Answer (score 2):

A validation rule should contain the conditions for failure. So if the stage is 4, and either max_discount is <5 or special_pricing_approved is true, then an error message should be shown.
So you formula should probably be:

```
AND(
   ISPICKVAL(StageName , "4. Proposal"),
   OR(
      Max_Discount__c <= 5,
      Special_Pricing_Approved__c = true
   )
)
```

Comment: @Rahul Take note to how writing a formula like this, makes it more readable and easier to understand. This helps to spot mistakes.

Comment: @guy I am still getting the same issue. Have updated my question with error I am getting on debug.

Comment: you said "when stage name is changed to "4. Proposal" then the max discount should be > 5 and Special_Pricing_Approved should be = false". Both are true in this case so there is not supposed to be an error, right? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @guy he mean the user should be able to change the stage to "4. Proposal" if max discount > 5 and Special_Pricing_Approved = false. If any of them do not certify the through an error. ie:- max discount < 5 OR  Special_Pricing_Approved = true then fire the validation rule. else dont do anything. allow them to change.

Comment: @Anu that is what my answer does indeed.